# Identify sub-domain from the list of Domains in LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap, cross-domain, ldap-query

In LDAP, I am able to find a list of domains when I run a query `(&(objectCategory=domain))` on `GC://`.

and result is,

```
DC=xyz,DC=com
DC=a,DC=xyz,DC=com
DC=b,DC=xyz,DC=com
```

Now, I want to identify which one is domain and which one is sub-domain based on LDAP property. Is it possible? If yes, then how can I identify that?

**Edit - 1**
I have one alternate way to find a list of domains using Forest `Forest.GetCurrentForest()`. And using `Parent` property we can check domain/subdomain. But in this case, I was able to find the forest in which my system domain belongs.

And I want to find Forest (domain list) from another domain forest. Is it possible using **DirectoryEntry**? Or any other way?
e.g. I am in domain abc.com and trying to find a list of domains for xyz.com.

As per my first question (main), I was able to find a list but not the parent-child relation. And as per my edit-1 comments, I can able to find the parent-child relationship but not able to find domain list from another forest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is to query the rootDSE for the attribute rootDomainNamingContext.

AFIK, that is the root of all, for any child domains.
The namingContexts should be the domain that the DC you are connected.

Let me know how I can help.
-jim

Comment: In my case I can't use rootDSE. As it provides details only for my current domain. While I am going to query for a different domain and finding a domain-subdomain list for it